# Can't I see a list of 'Others' in Foursquare herenow?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm writing a program looking for 'herenow' of Foursquare. As I attached, there are 2 people in the venues, but I can't see the people using the API, the API only returns an empty list.

Can't I see the members because they are with a type "others"? Isn't there any way to solve the problem?

```
hereNow: {count: 2,
...,
groups: [{type: "others",
...
count: 2,
items: [ ]
}
]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As akdotcom mentioned the documentation gives you the latest information on how the endpoint works: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow

There's been a change to how this endpoint works.

It used to be that it returned everybody currently checked-in at a venue (within 3 hours).

It's been changed so if you're not checked-in at a venue you can only see your friends (and friends of friends according to the current documentation) that are checked-in there, you cannot see non-friends.

Once you check-in you'll be able to see everybody with one exception, people that have opted out of appearing in herenow will not be shown though I believe are still reflected in the count.

I believe their explanation is this is more like the real world. If you're not physically there you cannot see who's there.

Only venue managers can see everybody checked-in without being checked-in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

See the endpoint documentation (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) for an overview of what "herenow" information is returned for different types of requests. You're probably making a "userless" request which only returns counts, no user information.